# Правильная замена в html?

Tags: javascript, html, django, node.js

Разбираю пример:
https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat

Там в папке templates есть .html файлы с Django кодом (спс Google), к примеру chat.html (несколько строк кода примера:
**<% block templates %>
    <% include 'includes/js/room.html' %>
<% endblock %>**

Так вот господа! Как правильно заменять такие вещи <% include 'includes/modals/account.html' %> на простые теги  и  ????
Подскажите пожалуйста!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно взять содержимое из `includes/modals/account.html` и вставить вместо `<% include 'includes/modals/account.html' %>`, например

Comment: Т.е. в этом файле добавить вместо инклудов то что есть в папке??

Comment: Да. Метод `include` - вставляет содержимое файла.

Comment: Добрый человек! Подскажи еще что:                                                      <% block css %><% endblock %>
    <$ 'vendor' | css | safe $>
    <$ 'style' | css | safe $>
    <$ 'vendor' | js | safe $>
    <% block js %><% endblock %> Что это значит

Comment: @EgorVoziyanov я так думаю, что `<% block css %>` - `<style>`,  а остальное - вставка js и css файлов